# PHP: foreach + array_map + array_filter it works as intended but can it be optimized?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

My array looks like this, the idea is to replace the RiD with names based on the numbers from a json file.

```
Array
(
[gId] => Value
[mId] => Value
[GM] => Value
[GT] => Value
[GQ] => Value
[participants] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [tId] => Value
                [sId1] => Value
                [sId2] => Value
                [tId] => Value
                [pId] => Value
                [SM] => Value 
                [R] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [c] => value
                                [RiD] => 5245
```

So to do that I've got the following where i use foreach, array_map and array_filter, it makes the array much bigger and change the structure of it. **So it work as intended, but is there anyway to optimize it?**

```
$p_final = array();

foreach($array["participants"] as $key => $value){

    $p = array();

        $p["RiD"] = $value["RiD"];

        $p["RiD"] = array_map(function($v) use($value, $rid_json) {
            $value["static"] = array_filter($rid_json["data"], function($s) use($v) {
                return $v["RiD"] == $s["id"];
            }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
            return $value;
        }, $value["RiD"]); 


    $p_final[$key] = $p;
}
```

Comment: Grab values from array and JSON, build new array with values, save new array over existing array (using `array_merge` or similar).

Comment: Hello Martin,

do i understand it right that, you want to solve it by using Json_decode, to make an array and merge these 2 arrays together?

Comment: I mean from my cursory look at the issue it very probably would be easier to simply set the value separately and simply overwrite the end product and combine both arrays.

Comment: unfortunately I can't dig too far into it right now, though `:-(`

Comment: Thanks for your input Martin, but I'm not quite sure what you mean. :(

Comment: when I get time later on I will try and write a full answer for you. :)

Comment: Thanks Martin, that would be really cool!

Comment: Hello again. Ok, first thoughts: If it works as it currently stands; do you have any evidence (timings) that the current structure is *inefficient*? We could go through a hugh code cycle simply to shave a few (very few) microseconds from the code process..... is it worth it?

Comment: Well it might not be as time inefficient however, it does create a really big array, it takes that array and multiply it with another array inside so i get a really huge array for no reason, so i was just wondering if there was a smarter solution.

Comment: Your question now sounds ambiguous. Please edit your question clearly stating what you would like to achieve (such as an example array structure). cheers